# I need to develop a method for another class, "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

This is the first class, I am developing one constructor and three methods so that the mpg of cars can be seen and stuffs:

{

```
public CarUser()
{
    Car honda = new Car(30.0);      // 30 miles per gallon

    honda.addGas(9.0);              // add 9 more gallons
    honda.drive(210.0);             // drive 210 miles

    // print range remaining
    System.out.println("Honda range remaining: " + honda.range());

    Car toyota = new Car(26.0);      // 26 miles per gallon

    toyota.addGas(4.5);              // add 4.5 more gallons
    toyota.drive(150.0);             // drive 150 miles

    // print range remaining
    System.out.println("Toyota range remaining: " + toyota.range());
}
```

This is the class I have made, and where I get "cannot find symbol 'range'" error:

```
public Car(double mpg)
{
   gas = 3.5;
   mpg = 0;

   Car myCar = new Car(0.0);

}
public void addGas(double amount)
{
    gas = gas + amount;
}
public void drive(double amount)
{
    gas = gas - (amount * (1/mpg));
}
public double range()
{
    gas = gas * mpg;
    return range;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any indications as to the correctness of your method, the symbol `range` used in the method `range()` isn't defined.

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
return gas * mpg;
```

Comment: thank you all! the error went away and now it's complaining about some other business but I've gotten much further than expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your range function, you are setting the variable named `gas` when I think you mean to name it `range`

Comment: hmm I went ahead and changed it and now it's telling me "cannot find symbol - variable range". I believe this is because there is no private instance for range, but as I understand it there shouldn't be? I'm just starting out with java, patience must be required XD
{
public double range()
    {
        range = gas * mpg;
        return range;
    }
}
that is what I put which I believe is what you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must return gas in your getter method.

```
public double range()
{
    gas = gas * mpg;
    return gas;
}
```

Comment: But this mutates the value of `gas`, which I would presume you don't want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `range` in the Car class, so it's complaining about that. You might want to do:

```
return gas*mpg;
```

instead or define range first:

```
public double range()
{
    int range = gas * mpg;
    return range;
}
```

Also, why are you creating another `Car` object inside the `Car` constructor? That seems wrong, remove it.